# Screwed up system my system (need expert help ASAP)

Tags: windows-10, bsod, bcd

Long story short, I'm an idiot.

A few days ago, I restarted my computer in the middle of AMD graphics drivers update, so Windows couldn't load in any way, and the "recovery options" seem useless as nothing Windows provide works. I have AMD Radeon Dual-X R9 280 Sapphire.

During the update, the screen started flickering (like it always does with updates) but I accidentally clicked the screen capture button so the Lightshot program started a screen capture layout, once I exited out of that the screen completely went black, I waited for a minute or so but the display didn't return, so the silly me brought up the idea of restarting it...while the driver was probably still updating.

After the restart, I get this following screen:

[image: BSOD]

so at this moment I knew I interrupted the graphics driver and now there's something wrong with it.

None of the troubleshoot options Windows provided is working (the enter and f8 options) as it keeps failing to load the driver. I tried removing the graphics card and using on-board graphics, but the same screen appears... It seems like it's an operating system error now and not hardware. I can give it back to my PC manufacturer, but it would take them weeks to return it, plus I'm worried they would format it which is the last thing I'd want. I have the official graphics driver CD AND the Windows 7 CD (I also have Windows 10 Recovery tools since I upgraded) if that helps.

A few days passed, many experts tried helping me on multiple forums but nothing worked, in fact, it just messed up my computer more and now the BCD file seems to be completely corrupt/gone (Marcium Reflect rescue tool did that). I did the bootrec commands but when I do the rebuildbcd it just says System drive not found.

I tried doing many things but stopped at some point because I knew I would mess it up even more, so I'm desperate right now. Is it possible to take out my SSD and plug it into another system to manually fix Windows? Or maybe a whole 16gb Windows OS on my USB and boot from it to fix? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: @IvanKhoury you're asked to improve format of your question, that has nothing to do with your native language.

Answer (score 0):

Accidents happen. In retrospect, you should make a system backup, or better yet, a disk image before updates or upgrades.

At this point, the safest thing to do would be to use anther PC to salvage any personal files [*and the Windows license key*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) from the SSD and then to reinstall Windows 10 from the latest media. You might get by without having to format the SSD, in which case you won't need the backup... or you might find you have to reformat the SSD to get the installation media started, in which case you'll need the license key.

Download the latest Windows 10 installation media from Microsoft, put it on USB or DVD (use AnyBurn or other ISO burning software, or use [Microsoft's Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/) to download and burn it to media.

Comment: I don't think I'll need the licence key, Windows 10 remembers my system and automatically activates itself. Also, how can I use another PC to do that? Like if I just plug my SSD in another computer does it automatically add it as another drive?

Comment: 1. If you need to wipe the drive before installing Windows again, it will *not* have the key. 2. If a PC has a second connector for a HDD, you should be able to plug it in and it *should* be recognized. An alternative is to get an external HDD/SDD enclosure, such as this US$15 one : https://www.amazon.com/Inateck-Inch-Drive-Enclosure-External/dp/B00FCLG65U .